# What are these metal fittings called?

Tags: woodworking

On the amazing [The Fletcher Capstan Table video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YX5QP2GCvwA), I can see some very useful metal fittings, but I can't for the life of me find them anywhere. This is probably because I don't know what they're called.

[image: Metal Biscuits]

I'd describe them as metal biscuits, which allow two pieces of wood to come together edge to edge, and align perfectly flush.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Metal biscuit joiners](http://www.leevalley.com/US/hardware/page.aspx?p=43253&cat=3,43715,43717), according to [Lee Valley Tools](http://www.leevalley.com/).

[image]

[Lamello](http://www.lamello.com), also offers a wide variety of [biscuit type connectors](http://www.lamello.com/en/products/wood-joining-system/joining-elements.html).

Comment: These are very close, but not quite the same. The ones on the Capstan Table so not need to slide to disengage.

Comment: I.E. the metal biscuit joiners are semi-permanent fittings, whereas the ones on the table are intended to connect and disconnect very easily.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet Well, they would either be called biscuits or plates, but I was not able to find anywhere online that sold metal ones. It's possible that whoever made the table, also custom made the biscuits.

Comment: Is there a general name for metal parts that go into furniture? "Furniture fittings" ?